# Powershell copy with wildcard

Tags: powershell, copy, wildcard, copy-item

The following works fine.
Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\EA\MT4\EA_bot.ex4  -Destination C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\0C2BFA140CA8FBEFEDCADDDEDD61AA24\MQL4\Experts\

However I want to do this for all directories that have the following wild carded, there are many instances:
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\*\MQL4\Experts\

Thank you,

I used * like in linux, that doesn't work in PS

Comment: To be clear: the wildcarded `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\*\MQL4\Experts\` is the SOURCE, right? you want to copy files FROM those directories to... whenever you need, is that correct?

Comment: Best to use XCOPY which is a cmd.exe command and will also work in Powershell.  To get more info open a cmd.exe window and type >Help XCOPY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually took this further, which might help others. This copies all `*.ex4` or all `*.ex5` files to ALL instances of MT4 or MT5 at one time with two commands. It copies from my local computer to the VPS servers; I just save the files to MT4 or MT5 locally. I changed the paths just for the fun of it; don't use your desktop, as Microsoft syncs that to their cloud, and it just makes stuff run slow.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\*\MQL4\Experts" -Directory | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path "\\tsclient\C\NOTYOURDESKTOPMICROSOFT\MT4\*.ex4" -Destination $_.FullName }
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\*\MQL5\Experts" -Directory | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path "\\tsclient\C\NOTYOURDESKTOPMICROSOFT\MT5\*.ex5" -Destination $_.FullName }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to loop over all the directories. You can do this in a one-liner.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\*\MQL4\Experts\" -Directory | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\EA\MT4\EA_bot.ex4" -Destination $_.FullName }
```

This will copy the `EA_bot.exe` to `MQL4\Experts\` under any directory in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\`

Comment: Dead on!  Thank you so much, such a time saver!